# How do we include only required modules from lodash in a Nuxt?Vuejs Project?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, lodash, nuxt.js

We have built a Nuxt/VueJS project.

Nuxt has its own config file called `nuxt.config.js` within which we configure webpack and other build setup.

In our package.json, we have included the lodash package.

In our code, we have been careful to load only import what we require, for example:

```
import orderBy from 'lodash/orderBy'
```

In `nuxt.config.js`, lodash is add to the `vendor` list.

However when we create the build, webpack always includes the entire `lodash` library instead of including only what we have used in our code.

I have read numerous tutorials but haven't got the answer. Some of those answers will surely work if it was a webpack only project. But in our case, it is through nuxt config file.

Looking forward to some help.

Below is the partial nuxt.config.js file. Only relevant/important parts are included:

```
const resolve = require('resolve')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
  },
  modules: [
    ['@nuxtjs/component-cache', { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 10 }]
  ],
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/intersection', ssr: false },
  ],
  build: {
    vendor: ['moment', 'lodash'],
    analyze: {
      analyzerMode: 'static'
    },
    postcss: {
      plugins: {
        'postcss-custom-properties': false
      }
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)
    ],
    /*
    ** Run ESLINT on save
    */
    extend (config, ctx) {
      // config.resolve.alias['create-api'] = `./create-api-${ctx.isClient ? 'client' : 'server'}.js`

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the vendor list is telling webpack to include the entire package. Do you get an import error if you remove it from the vendor list?

Comment: @cgTag I just removed it from the vendor list. There is no error, but there is no change either. Full lodash is still a part of the vendor bundle.

Comment: What if you try the global reference like this `import orderBy from 'lodash'`. WebPack 2 and above will only import the single function. You don't have to define the path to the function.

Comment: Removing lodash from vendor still got it in vendor.js probably because of this - In Nuxt, a module is extracted into the vendor chunk when it's inside node_modules and used in at-least 1/2 of the total pages.

Comment: That sounds like Nuxt isn't using WebPack for bundling or it's doing a lot of the bundle work for it. I guess that's part of the template compiling needed for production. That's a shame as WebPack's tree shaking can do a better job. https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

Comment: Nuxt is using webpack, and provides a way to include webpack plugins and even extend it. My problem is I don't know how and where to configure. Is there a way I can share the config file here?

Comment: You can add it to the question.

Comment: Added to the question.

Comment: Sidenote: I'd strongly recommend to switch from `moment` to `date-fns` as well to reduce your file size.

Comment: @asanas I see you have the same problem as I, and you even use moment.js. I import moment like you do in the vendor file, but it imports all the unnecessary locale files – I just need one.
I see you have an ignore plugin, but I don't really understand. How do you use it. And how do you use moment.js in your components?
(I am still importing moment into my components: `import moment from 'moment'`. I would be very glad if you could give some help here.
cheers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can `npm install` only the required packages

Lodash can be split up per [custom builds](https://lodash.com/custom-builds). You can find a list of already available ones [here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/tree/4.6.1-npm-packages). You can use them like this: `npm i -S lodash.orderby`. I didn't check it but you would probably also need to change `import orderBy from 'lodash/orderBy'` to `import orderBy from 'lodash.orderby'`.

Comment: We did make a custom build using lodash cli and loaded only the packages we wanted in our build. the package is much smaller now.

Comment: you can achieve smaller size with tree-shaking as well but with less fuss of npm installing each function

Comment: @Claudiu Can you give an answer to show how that is done?